# QtConcurrent map error c2440

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I'm making an app for recognizing license plates in images. It works fine, but now I want to move the image analysis part of the code to a separate thread. I'm using Qt 5.4. After reading the documentation I decided that `QtConcurrent::map` was the right thing to use because before processing the images the user loads files (only their names) which are stored in a list. Here's some code:

Definition of the function that's supposed to be run in a thread:

```
results detectPlates(const QString &file);
```

Attempt to use multithreading:

```
QFuture<results> r = QtConcurrent::map(files, &MainWindow::detectPlates)
```

`files` is defined as `QList<QString>`
`results` is a type defined inside a library that i am using, if that is important.

This doesn't compile with the error :

```
C2440 'initializing' cannot convert from `QFuture<void>` to `QFuture<results>`
```

When I modify the function to be `<void>` then I get:

```
error c2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument.
```

What is the problem? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QtConcurrent::map` modifies the items in place, and returns a void future. If you want to return the result in the form of a `QFuture<T>`, you will want to use `QtConcurrent::mapped`.

Comment: [This Qt 5.4 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qtconcurrentmap.html) explains, nicely, the difference between the various `QtConcurrent` mapping functions.

Comment: @ajshort Thanks for a reply. I tried that but it still gives the same error. I even tried with a dummy function that returns an `int` and mapped a `QVector` of `ints` to it and even that doesn't work. It works however in a console application without any problems. I am totally lost with this.